# Is chocolate that was in contact with moldy vegetables safe to eat after washing?

Tags: chocolate, vegetables

If a small part of a piece chocolate was in contact with some moldy vegetables leaves for a day, will the chocolate be safe to eat after washing it with water? The chocolate bar itself didn't have any mold on it.

Comment: Welcome! Please note that we explicitly exclude health questions except for food safety. I edited your question to be on topic. If that’s not what you wanted to know, I’m sorry we can’t really help. Please take the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works. That said, we as humans are exposed to mold spores every single day and at least a healthy person’s immune system can handle a certain amount without immediate ill effects. I personally doubt that a single exposure to trace amounts will matter, but I am not a doctor.

Comment: I would *really* love to know how this situation was even allowed to happen. Unwrapped chocolate in a fridge alongside vegetables, again neither wrapped nor in the crisper & left until they went mouldy... What else is missing from the hygiene regime in that fridge?

Comment: @Tetsujin the chocolate was not in the fridge, neither the vegetable was. My brother unwrapped the chocolate bar and broke it into two pieces. He took one piece and wrapped the other piece and left it for me. My mom kept some leafy greens beside it. Somehow the chocolate bar came in contact with the vegetables. I noticed them after one or two days later, the vegetables had some molds on them and the wrapping was not done well, small part of it was touching the vegetables.

Comment: @Stephie♦ thank you. I am new here, just have signed up. I didn't know about that. Of course you have some rules here and I will follow them. I have depression and having health anxiety lately and have self-diagnosed with various types of health problems including HIV, various types of cancers, neurodegenerative diseases and so many other things, on the internet. I have some swollen lymph nodes for about 6 months and I had all these things to worry untill I ate that chocolate. Now, a new thing is added to them.

Answer (score 1):

*My personal opinion:  I don't think you would be at risk for any health issues beyond potentially throwing up the chocolate after you eat it.*
I once bought something from a local gas/market and was eating it before I realized that it was moldy. Promptly got sick. I'm not sure if getting sick was caused from actually eating it, or because I saw the mold. Either way, my body responded in a natural way. And I think you would (also) throw up if the chocolate bar was truly bad. I'm not sure that the conditions you describe would put you in any serious risk... but I really can't say (not there, can't see it, examine it, etc.) The important thing is, what do you think? If you really think it would make you sick, throw it away. 
 
I am sorry to hear that you have so many health concerns. Going online to try and make sense of this pain, or that ache would give most healthy people a reason to worry. But some of the conditions you have "self-diagnosed" are serious health concerns. Please take the initiative to see a health care professional and find out for sure if you do (or do not) have health issues that would require medication. There is no reason to panic over things you "might have", better to find out from a doctor and then decide how to deal with it.